# Get category from post nibbleblog script?

Tags: php, categories

I want to get correct category link where post has posted!

Simple example: http://news.filmground.host-ed.me/

Look "Author: Elar", so next after that should be a category link like "Category: Game News"!

I think source code is here, taken from plugin "categories"

code is here

```
<?php
// =====================================================================
// PLUGIN INFO
// =====================================================================
$_PLUGIN_CONFIG['DATA'] = array(
    'author'=>'Diego Najar',
    'version'=>'3.6',
    'url'=>'http://www.nibbleblog.com'
);


// =====================================================================
// PLUGIN CLASS
// =====================================================================
class PLUGIN_CATEGORIES extends Plugin
{
    public function blog_body()
    {
        global $categories;

        $html = '<ul>';

        foreach($categories as $category)
        {
            // URL generator
            $href = Url::category($category['slug']);

            $html .= '<li class="category"><a href="'.$href.'">'.$category['name'].'</a></li>';
        }

        $html .= '</ul>';

        return $html;
    }
}

?>
```

and page where this goes is here

```
<header>
    <h1 class="post-title">
        <a href="<?php echo Post::permalink() ?>"><?php echo Post::title() ?></a>
    </h1>
     <div class="post-published"><span style="font-size:13px"><img alt="Date when post was added!" src="img/dd.png" style="height:13px; margin-bottom:-2px; margin-top:0px; width:13px" title="Date when post was added!" /> Posted on:</span> <?php echo Post::published() ?> | <img alt="Date when post was added!" src="img/au.png" style="height:13px; margin-bottom:-2px; margin-top:0px; width:13px" title="Post author!" /> Author: <a href="">Elar</a></div>

</header>

<div class="post-content">
    <?php echo Post::content() ?>
</div>
<footer>
        <span class="comment-count">
            <?php echo Post::comment_count_link() ?>
        </span>

    <div class="post-tags"><?php echo Post::tags ()?></div>

</footer>
```

And also how get commas between tags?

```
<div class="post-tags"><?php echo Post::tags ()?></div>
```

I am using nibbleblog blog script!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For category try to add this to your html

```
<a href="<?php echo Post::category('permalink') ?>"><?php echo Post::category() ?></a>
```

And for tags this should work:

```
<?php
$tagLinks = array();
foreach (Post::tags(TRUE) as $tag) {
    $tagLinks[] = '<a class="tag" href="' . Url::tag($tag['name']) . '">' . $tag['name_human'].'</a>';
}
?>
<div class="post-tags"><?php echo implode(', ', $tagLinks); ?></div>
```

Comment: Excellent, works perfectly! Now i need only get commas between tags!